# Bot Framework - Oauth BadRequest - https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect

Tags: laravel, azure, oauth, botframework, laravel-passport

I am trying to get a Bot working with the Oauth example provided here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Cjavascript

If I use Azure as an exemplary issuer all works ok. So the general code works out fine.

Now, I have an example Laravel Passport app running to issue myself for testing purposes. All configuration, normal login etc. works fine. I created a generic oauth 2 client in Azure with my password client id and secret.

If I test it in the Azure Portal it heads to the `request permission` dialog. I confirm and it redirects to e.g. `https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect?code=XYZ&state=123` and just shows `Bad Request`. No more, no less.

I tried different configurations etc., googled and found some with similar problems but no solution. Most just referred to secrets etc. But the secret works, a broken secret before lead to other issues I am not facing now.

And the error message is not really helpful ^^ No matter how I call `https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect` it is always a Bad Request.

Does anybody have an idea, a hint in what direction to look further, where issues could occur? As I am a little lost right now.

Comment: Have you [tested the connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Cjavascript#test-your-connection) to see if its working as expected? Do you notice any additional error log on the Dev Console?

Comment: Hey @ranusharao, the test already fails as mentioned above.

Comment: Hello, we are facing the same issue. Our login provider is Azure B2C, we are able to log in but it redirects back to the bot framework with a 404 error of: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.